# I am trying to prove that the cardinality of P(N) (the set of all finite subsets in N) is equal to the cardinality of N.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here, N refers to the set of all natural numbers, and P refers to the power set of N. Let the number of finite subsets be equal to F. I am having trouble representing the cardinality of the power set. :)

Comment: Yes thank you! I will check it out

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Usually $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$, the power set of $\mathbb N$, has *all* subsets of $\mathbb N$, not just finite ones

Comment: Well this one represents finite ones :)

Comment: I have shown that the set of finite subsets of N is countable. How do I go from there to show that it has the same cardinality as |N|

Comment: @Bryce what does “countable” mean?